# Efficient implementation of Faulhaber's Formula

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, combinations

I want an efficient implementation of [Faulhaber's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

I want answer as

> F(N,K) % P

where F(N,K) is implementation of faulhaber's forumula and P is a prime number.

**Note: N is very large upto 10^16 and K is upto 3000**

I tried the [double series implementation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html) in the given site. But its too much time consuming for very large n and k. Can any one help making this implementation more efficient or describe some other way to implement the formula.

Comment: Is this from Project Euler? I suspect that you need to exploit more deeply the fact that the computation is mod P.

Comment: Yes i thought about it, but Bernoulli numbers are in fraction so it is hard to exploit. But I don't know...

Comment: I think someone commented here before that this question may be from here: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/infinitum-mar14/challenges/summing-the-k-n-series . There, K is up to 10^3 (1000) and P = 10^9 + 7.

Comment: I think I made it work. Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using Schultz' (1980) idea, outlined below the double series implementation ([mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html)) that you mentioned?

From Wolfram MathWorld:

Schultz (1980) showed that the sum `S_p(n)` can be found by writing

[image]

and solving the system of p+1 equations

[image]

obtained for j=0, 1, ..., p (Guo and Qi 1999), where `delta (j,p)` is the [Kronecker delta](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerDelta.html).

Below is an attempt in Haskell that seems to work. It returns a result for n=10^16, p=1000 in about 36 seconds on my old laptop PC.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}

import Math.Combinatorics.Exact.Binomial
import Data.Ratio
import Data.List (foldl')

kroneckerDelta a b | a == b    = 1 % 1
                   | otherwise = 0 % 1

g a b = ((-1)^(a - b +1) * choose a b) % 1

coefficients :: Integral a => a -> a -> [Ratio a] -> [Ratio a]
coefficients p j cs
  | j < 0     = cs
  | otherwise = coefficients p (j - 1) (c:cs)
 where
   c = f / g (j + 1) j
   f = foldl h (kroneckerDelta j p) (zip [j + 2..p + 1] cs)
   h accum (i,cf) = accum - g i j * cf

trim r = let n = numerator r
             d = denominator r
             l = div n d
         in (mod l (10^9 + 7),(n - d * l) % d)

s n p = numerator (a % 1 + b) where
 (a,b) = foldl' (\(i',r') (i,r) -> (mod (i' + i) (10^9 + 7),r' + r)) (0,0) 
      (zipWith (\c i ->  trim (c * n^i)) (coefficients p p []) [1..p + 1])

main = print (s (10^16) 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered my own algorithm to calculate the coefficients of the polynomial obtained from Faulhaber's formula; it, its proof and several implementations can be found at [github.com/fcard/PolySum](https://github.com/fcard/PolySum). This question inspired me to include a c++ implementation (using the GMP library for arbitrary precision numbers), which, as of the time of writing and minus several usability features, is:

```cpp
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <vector>

namespace polysum {
  typedef std::vector<mpq_class> mpq_row;
  typedef std::vector<mpq_class> mpq_column;
  typedef std::vector<mpq_row>   mpq_matrix;

  mpq_matrix make_matrix(size_t n) {
    mpq_matrix A(n+1, mpq_row(n+2, 0));
    A[0] = mpq_row(n+2, 1);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
      for (size_t j = i; j < n+1; j++) {
        A[i][j] += A[i-1][j];
        A[i][j] *= (j - i + 2);
      }
      A[i][n+1] = A[i][n-1];
    }
    A[n][n+1] = A[n-1][n+1];
    return A;
  }

  void reduced_row_echelon(mpq_matrix& A) {
    size_t n = A.size() - 1;
    for (size_t i = n; i+1 > 0; i--) {
      A[i][n+1] /= A[i][i];
      A[i][i] = 1;
      for (size_t j = i-1; j+1 > 0; j--) {
        auto p = A[j][i];
        A[j][i] = 0;
        A[j][n+1] -= A[i][n+1] * p;
      }
    }
  }

  mpq_column sum_coefficients(size_t n) {
    auto A = make_matrix(n);
    reduced_row_echelon(A);

    mpq_column result;
    for (auto row: A) {
      result.push_back(row[n+1]);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

We can use the above like so:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <polysum.h>

mpq_class power_sum(size_t K, unsigned int N) {
  auto coeffs = polysum::sum_coefficients(K)

  mpq_class result(0);
  for (size_t i = 0; i <= K; i++) {
    result += A[i][n+1] * pow(N, i+1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The full implementation provides a `Polynomial` class that is printable and callable, as well as a `polysum` function to construct one as a sum of another polynomial.

```cpp
#include "polysum.h"

void power_sum_print(size_t K, unsigned int N) {
  auto F = polysum::polysum(K);
  std::cout << "polynomial: " << F;
  std::cout << "result: " << F(N);
}
```

As for efficiency, the above calculates the result for `K=1000` and `N=1e16` in about `1.75` seconds on my computer, compared to the much more mature and optimized SymPy implementation which takes about `90` seconds on the same machine, and mathematica which takes `30` seconds. For `K=3000` the above takes about `4` minutes, mathematica took almost `20` minutes, (but uses much less memory) and I left sympy running all night but it didn't finish, maybe due to it running out of memory.

Among the optimizations that can be done here are making the matrix sparse and taking advantage of the fact that only half of the rows and columns need to be calculated. The Rust version in the linked repository implements the sparse and rows optimizations, and  takes about `0.7` seconds to calculate `K=1000`, and about `45` to calculate `K=3000` (using `105mb` and `2.9gb` of memory respectively). The Haskell version implements all three optimizations and takes about `1` second for `K=1000` and about `34` seconds for `K=3000`. (using `60mb` and `880mb` of memory respectively) and  The completely unoptimized python implementation takes about `12` seconds for `K=1000` but runs out of memory for `K=3000`.

It's looking like this method is the fastest regardless of the language used, but the research is ongoing. Since Schultz's method also boils down to solving a system of `n+1` equations and should be able to be optimized the same way, it will depend on whether his matrix is faster to calculate or not. Also, memory usage is not scaling well at all, and Mathematica is still the clear winner here, using only `80mb` for `K=3000`. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a simple Julia script from [the formula that Faulhaber missed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xHkn1po6fo) (just like the 20,000 other formulas in his subject that he missed and that were since discovered, shame on him).

```
function faulhaber(d)
    polyVector = [big(0)//big(1) for n = 1:d+2]
    #initialisation at d = 1, indices shifted by 1!
    polyVector[2] = 1/2
    polyVector[3] = 1/2
    for j=2:d
        oldUnit = polyIntEval(polyVector, 1)
        for k=j+2:-1:3
            polyVector[k] = j * polyVector[k-1]/(k-1)
        end
        polyVector[2] = 1 - j*oldUnit
    end
    return polyVector
end

function polyIntEval(v, x)
    d = length(v) - 1
    result = 0
    for j=0:d
        result += v[j+1]*x^(j+1) / (j+1)
    end
    return result
end
```

On my laptop, it took about 5sec to get the complete polynomial for d = 1000.

Comment: d = 3000 takes about half a minute. So probably this really is superior to the other methods.